# AWS - Lambda Scheduler to invoke multiple lambda instances

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-swf

I need to poll a DB every 5 minutes , get the list of ids from the db and make service call to external services for each an every id to get additional information and store the data in db. I thought of building a lambda scheduler that would fetch the list of ids from db and invoke 1 lambda instance for each and every id fetched from db. The lambda instance which is invoked by the scheduler will call the external service for the specific id that it has received from the scheduler and it will persist the info in a db. Is this a feasible pattern for the problem or are there any other patterns available for implementing this use case in aws?

Comment: What sort of database are you using? If you use DynamoDB, you can use DynamoDB Streams to trigger a Lambda directly for each id.

Answer (score 1):

My design would be to use a cloudwatch event rule that fires the first lambda function every 5 minutes to gather the list of ids.

That lambda function would the send a message for each id that needs to be processed to an SNS topic, and then I would subscribe the second lambda function to that SNS topic so it would receive the id/message and do the required work.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html

Comment: Thank you. Should I have a lambda consumer that in turn instantiates several lambda works to do the actual job? Can the first lambda bundle the ids into batches of 10? I want my lambda consumer to read the next message only after the first message is processed. I would like to have some throttling mechanism in place to ensure I am not overloading the db.

Comment: @PunterVicky There's no need to add complexity by having another lambda function to coordinate a fanout while processing the SNS messages—best to keep it simple and have 1 Lambda for 1 SNS notification. You can configure a maximum allowed concurrency for a Lambda function, and if you want the SNS messages to be processed serially, you can set the max concurrency to 1.